# JQuery FullCalendar Adding Event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am working on a calendaring application with PHP and I am using jQuery Fullcalendar(http://fullcalendar.io/).  I am able to get the calendar to display, but I have run up against the wall on adding events to the calendar:

1) With the click of a mouse I want to pop-up a dialog to create the event

2) By clicking an existing event, I would like to update the event

3) By hovering over an event, I would like to pop-up a dialog to show details.

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find a basic example with CRUD on FullCalendar in my GitHub repo. Check it out [**here**](https://github.com/tliokos/jquery-fullcalendar-crud).

The code is not meant to be used in a production environment, but rather help you get started with FullCalendar and PHP.